Error installing driver via make due to GCC-12 version not matching
Trying to install drivers that via a make command, but getting the error:
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic'

Initially did not have gcc-12 (fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.4) and used sudo apt install gcc-12 (and noting that the instructions for install already had me install Linux headers / build essential via sudo apt install linux-headers-generic and sudo apt install build-essential).
I have tried numerous solutions (over the course of many fresh Ubuntu installs) trying to change the symbolic link for example, but I am struggling to make progress.

Is your /usr/bin/gcc-12 a link to /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12?  Either a manual install of gcc-12 or the automatic install via dependencies should work, no link changes needed on your part (for the Nvidia module build anyway). What module are you building?

I just used readlink -f /usr/bin/gcc-12 and the output confirmed as /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12. This is a replacement driver for cx8800 module (driver git here: https://github.com/happycube/cxadc-linux3/)

Try the build after booting the (original) 5.15 kernel. That one should use the default gcc-11.  The check seems to really find the same gcc-12 compiler, but just complains, so maybe just edit the compiler check out of the make files. Did you try the GCC= and CC= redefinitions of env variables?
